# A Problem on Time Complexity of Algorithms

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, asymptotics, complexity-classes, lower-bounds

For every integer $t$, is there a problem whose solutions can be verified in $O(n^{s})$ time but cannot be found in $O(n^{st})$ time?

By verifying, I mean that given a candidate solution $y$, we can judge whether $y$ is correct or not in time $O(n^s)$.

Comment: I'm not familliar with $\omega$ notation, do you mean $\Omega$ notation?

Comment: I edited your question to reflect your comment on the A.Schulz answer, I don't know if this edit is correct or not, but IMO Schulz answer was correct before this edit.

Comment: @jmite $\omega$ notation is standard [Landau notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).  It is to $\Omega$ as $o$ is to $O$.

Comment: What is the restriction on $s$?  Recall that if $T(n) = \omega(f)$ then $T(n) = O(f)$.  Did you mean, as jmite asks for $\Omega$?

Comment: "Can be computed in $\omega(n^5)$ time" does _not_ mean the same thing as "cannot be computed in $O(n^5)$ time".  It is possible to buy a pencil for more than a million dollars, but that doesn't imply that I can't buy a pencil for less than a million dollars.

Comment: What's the quantifier on $s$?  Do you mean "For all integers $s$ and $t$, is there a problem..." or do you mean "For every integer $t$, is there an integer $s$ and a problem..." or do you mean "Is there an integer $s$ such that for every integer $t$ there is a problem..."?

Comment: For every integer t, ... . any reasonable value for s is ok. e.g. obviously s = 0 is not ok!

Answer (score 4):

For $k = \left\lceil \dfrac{r}{2} \right\rceil$, it is [conjectured](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/TOPP/P11.html) (and proven in some simpler models of computation by JeffE) that $r$-SUM problem has lower bounds $\Omega(n^k)$, the solution for which can be verified in $O(n)$ time.

Pick an $r$ such that $k \gt t$, implying $\omega(n^t)$ bounds.

Comment: Where is it proven?

Comment: @Shayan: Did you check out the link? (click on conjectured in the answer)

Comment: You can find my $r$-SUM lower bound paper [here](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/~jeffe/pubs/linsat.html) and a more readable followup paper [here](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~chazelle/pubs/lindegen-jacm.pdf).

Comment: But the answer is proved for "simpler models of computation" not generally.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, it is okay if $s=t=1$. In this case take *sorting* in some comparison based model. You can verify a correct solution with $O(n)$ comparisons. On the other hand you need $\Omega(n \log n)\subsetneq \omega(n)$ comparisons to sort.

Comment: But I want to solve it for every integer t. Not a single sample.